# Maximize the expression $y(4-ay)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

> Let $a,y \in \mathbb R$ such that $a>0$. Find the value of $y$ that maximises the expression $y(4-ay)$. Do not use calculus.

I think the question is about AGM and don't think there is a way to find the actual y value. So I try the AGM formula.
Why is my answer wrong?
The picture of the question and the answer:
[image]

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired. Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources.

Comment: You're on the right track, but I would maximise $ay(4 - ay)$ instead. Note: the extra factor of $a > 0$ will not change the $y$ value where the minimum is achieved, but will multiply the minimum value by $a$. Try your method again, and you should get a maximum value that depends only on $a$, not on the dummy variable $y$.

Comment: Hint:try competing a square.

Comment: @terry Contrary to what you have said, there **is** a way to find the actual $y$ value. In general, for a function $f(y) = ay^2 + by + c$ with $a < 0$, it is possible to find the $y$ value for which $f(y)$ is maximized.

Comment: @theo I got y(4-ay) <= 4/a and the equality holds when y= 2/a. Thank you!

Comment: @insipidintegrator I don't get where to complete a square.

Comment: @ben yes, but the question is ask for a > 0.

Comment: @terry The $a$ I used in my comment is not the same as the $a$ from your problem. I meant that because the expression can be written as $(-a)y^2 + 4y + 0$ and because $-a < 0)$, the expression must attain a maximum.

Comment: To be more specific, the parabola $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ has its vertex at $x = \frac{-b}{2a}$.  (Note that this is the arithmetic mean of the two roots found with the Quadratic Formula, the $\pm$ parts cancelling each other out.)  This is a minimum if $a > 0$, or a maximum if $a < 0$.

Comment: @Ben I get it. Thank you!

Comment: @Dan got it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To complete the square,
$$y(4-ay)=4y-ay^2=-(ay^2-4y)$$$$=-a\left(y^2-4\dfrac ya\right)=-a\left(y^2-2\cdot \frac 2a\cdot y\right)$$$$=-a\left(y^2-2\cdot \frac 2a\cdot y+\frac{4}{a^2}-\frac{4}{a^2}\right)=\frac 4a-a\left(y-\frac 2a\right)^2$$

Now, this is an expression where a non-negative value is being subtracted from a positive number. It will attain its maximum value when the least possible value is subtracted from it. So to maximise the entire expression, we make the quantity being subtracted as $0$.

So the maxima occurs at $y=\dfrac 2a$ and the maximum value is $\dfrac 4a$.

Note: for a general quadratic expression $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, where $a,b,c\in \mathbb R, a<0$, the maximum value occurs for $y=-\dfrac {b}{2a}$ and the maximum value is $\dfrac {4ac-b^2}{4a}$.